# TypeError: function missing 4 required positional arguments

Tags: python, kivy

I've hit a problem calling a function inside a class. The code fragment is:

```
    class CharacterGenerator(GridLayout):

        def printcharacter(self,my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb):
            printable_stats = print_stats(my_sb)
            printable_rolls = print_rolls(my_cr)
            printable_scm = print_scm(my_scm)
            printable_scb = print_scb(my_scb)

    #       self.clear_widgets()
            layout=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
            stat_box=(Label(text_size=(300, None),
                    text='Stats\n' + str(printable_stats)))
            rolls_box=(Label(text_size=(300, None),
                    text='Rolls\n' + str(printable_rolls)))
            scm_box=(Label(text_size=(300, None),
                    text='SCM\n' + str(printable_scm)))
            scb_box=(Label(text_size=(300, None),
                    text='SCB\n' + str(printable_scb)))

            layout.add_widget(stat_box)
            layout.add_widget(rolls_box)
            layout.add_widget(scm_box)
            layout.add_widget(scb_box)
            wayout = Button(text='Way Out')
            layout.add_widget(wayout)

        def human(self,a,b):
            if b==True: 
                self.Status="human"
                race=self.Status
                statblock = human()
                characteristic_rolls = rolls(statblock)
                skill_category_modifiers = scm(statblock)
                skill_category_bonuses = scb(statblock)
                CharacterGenerator.printcharacter         (self,     statblock, characteristic_rolls, skill_category_modifiers, skill_category_bonuses)
```

It errors with:

```
       File "./charactergenerator.kv", line 36, in <module>
         on_press: root.printcharacter()
     TypeError: printcharacter() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'my_sb', 'my_cr', 'my_scm', and 'my_scb'
```

As far as I can tell, I am sending the right parameters to the `printcharacter` function. The same function and call work with `printcharacter` in a separate python module.

I've tried all combinations of the calling parameters, added and removed some from the list. Without the `CharacterGenerator.printcharacter` call, all I get is the message that `CharacterGenerator has no object printcharacter` and I'm back to square one.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Here is the kv file. I really can't get the formatting correct on this site :( `<CharacterGenerator>:
    cols: 2
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: .2,.2,.2
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text: 'Human'
    CheckBox:
        group: 'race_group'
        on_active: root.human(*args)
    Button:
        text: 'Next'
        on_press: root.printcharacter()`

Comment: you should put it in your question. paste it, then highlight it all, and press ctrl+k

Comment: what shall `my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb` be, when called from your .kv file. (When you press the "Next" Button)?

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be in your charactergenerator.kv on line 36.

There you call the function, "on_press: root.printcharacter()" without parameters.

So call the function with parameters.

And change this line

`def printcharacter(self,my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb):`

to

`def printcharacter(self,my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb,*args):`

Comment: I've changed line 36 to: `on_press: root.printcharacter(statblock,characteristic_rolls,skill_category_modifiers,skill_category_bonuses)` but now get the error ` TypeError: printcharacter() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given`

Comment: I changed KV line 36 back to `on_press: root.printcharacter()` and the definition to `def printcharacter(my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb,*args):` . Now I get the error "   File "brp_chargen.py", line 26, in printcharacter
     printable_stats = print_stats(my_sb)
   File "/home/colin/PROJECTS/programming/pythondev/learn_python/kivy/brp_chargen_02/brp_stats.py", line 50, in print_stats
     s = s + stat + " [" + str(mystats[stat]) + "] "
 TypeError: 'CharacterGenerator' object is not subscriptable" .(PS I didn't downgrade your first answer).

Comment: @ColinBrett I did not say it was you. Anyways. dont change the line in the .kv file back. only the one with *args. BTW are my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb accesable in your kv file. ?

Comment: The KV file looks like this now `on_press: root.printcharacter(statblock,characteristic_rolls,skill_category_modifiers,skill_category_bonuses)` . The function def looks like `def printcharacter(my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb):` . I get the error: `   File "./charactergenerator.kv", line 36, in <module>
     on_press: root.printcharacter(statblock,characteristic_rolls,skill_category_modifiers,skill_category_bonuses)
 NameError: name 'statblock' is not defined` . None of the variables (statblock, my_sb and so on) are "visible" to the KV file. How do I do this?

Comment: @ColinBrett the answer says, `def printcharacter(self,my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb,*args):`

Comment: I changed the definition to `def printcharacter(self,my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb,*args):` . Now the error reads `TypeError: printcharacter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'my_scb'` . So some of the positional arguments are being recognised, just one is "missing". The KV file reads `on_press: root.printcharacter()`

Comment: @ColinBrett Can you plz show your whole .kv file in your question. Not in the comment section.

Comment: Can I post the kv file elsewhere?

Comment: @ColinBrett yes `dpaste.com`

Answer (score -1):

Use **`self`** to call function, in code `CharacterGenerator.printcharacter(self, ...`- you aren't passing self as first argument, so proper `printcharacter` call suppose to be:

```
self.printcharacter(statblock, characteristic_rolls, skill_category_modifiers, skill_category_bonuses)
```

You can read more about `self` on [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python).

**Shortly**: if you defined method within class definition without [staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) or [staticclass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator it would accept class instance method was called on as first argument ( by convention that first argument called `self`), that argument shouldn't be passed directly as it would be passed automatically when instance method would be called.

I've noticed that `printcharacter` method doesn'y operate with `self`, so you can define it as staticmethod:

```
class CharacterGenerator(GridLayout):

    @staticmethod
    def printcharacter(my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb):
        # method body
```

And call it next way:

```
# within execution of instance method
self.printcharacter(statblock, characteristic_rolls, skill_category_modifiers, skill_category_bonuses)
# Anywhere outside class method 
CharacterGenerator.printcharacter(statblock, characteristic_rolls, skill_category_modifiers, skill_category_bonuses)
```

Comment: I used your code and changed the function def to `def printcharacter(my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb):` . Now I get the error: ` TypeError: printcharacter() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given`

Comment: @ColinBrett Add @staticmethod decorator if that function shouldn't operate with `self` attribute, i've updated answer..

Comment: I've never used static methods. I tried `    def @printcharacter(my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb):` but this gave an "invalid syntax" error.

Comment: @ColinBrett yeah, there are syntax error, see part of my answer to get proper way of adding staticmethod decorator

Comment: This is not answering his question or solving the error. Its more like a tutorial on static methods

Comment: I've tried Andriy's suggestions. `@staticmethod
    def printcharacter(my_sb,my_cr,my_scm,my_scb):` and call with `            CharacterGenerator.printcharacter(statblock,characteristic_rolls,skill_category_modifiers,skill_category_bonuses)` which gives the error: "   File "./charactergenerator.kv", line 36, in <module>
     on_press: root.printcharacter()
 TypeError: printcharacter() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'my_sb', 'my_cr', 'my_scm', and 'my_scb'". So I guess the kv file needs to be updated to include the parameters but how do I reference them from the py file?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko. There is no charactergenerator.py file. The only way I can reference the printcharacter routine is by prefixing the CharacterGenerator class.

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN you are right, answer giving answer of how to use static method decorator. However fact that suggestion to use decorator needs more text to explain than suggestion for properly passing argument which is suppose to fix OP problem doesn't make that answer tutorial... Have a good day )

Comment: Thank you. Good day to you too :)

Comment: @ColinBrett the problem there is obviously, that thos variables are not accessible in your kv file. What are those? where do you expect to get the values from?

Comment: The variables are created by the call at the end of def human, the line reading `CharacterGenerator.printcharacter(statblock,characteristic_rolls,skill_category_modifiers,skill_category_bonuses)` . The whole function is posted at the start of this thread. How do I make the variables visible to the kv file?

Comment: @ColinBrett `from kivy.properties import StringProperty` then in the beginning of your class you instantiate them as so `my_sb = StringProperty()` then in your .kv file you acces by `root.my_sb`

Comment: @ColinBrett and in human you do `self.my_sb = characteristic_rolls` and remove that CharacterGenerator.printcharacter call

Comment: @ColinBrett as the matter of fact your approach to this app is kind of wrong. Take a look at the pong game tutorial https://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN . Thanks for the assist. Looks like I'll have to rewrite some of my code in line with the Pong tutorial. Colin.